# Add column from development database table to production database table

Tags: sql-server, database, alter-table

I got an issue When some table on the development database has more columns added, and right now I should add the column in the production database.

I try to add the column manually, by Add Column on Table Tree, but when I try to save, it show me a `warning`:

[image]

here's the complete warning message :

> ```
> Saving Definition Changes to tables with large amounts of data could take a 
>  considerable amount of time. While changes are being saved, 
>  table data will not be accessible.
> ```

is this safe? or is there another method to do this ?

**UPDATE :** I Tried to click `Yes` but after some minutes it give me another warning that said `Time Out`, and the process canceled, and yes the data in the production table is totally huge

Comment: AS you can see, full message is not visible, copy and post full message here.

Comment: @SQL.NETWarrior Sorry, I Already Update the Question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically this means that the SQL server is going to go over all the records in the table (on disk) and change them.
This is an operation that will take a lot of IO and will lock your table to reading / writing.

Something else to consider is your DB timeout as mentioned in
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/7d46b158-a089-48c9-8153-53c5ed116d37/sql-2005-updating-table-definition-with-large-amounts-of-data-timeout

This is relatively safe (except for the lock issue) and will be the case in any method you will use (maybe without the nice UI warning).

Comment: so it's likely could get Lock Issue, i also read on your link, `Alter Table Script works like a charm` is it the solution?

Comment: @SabilValdano - both options will call alter table eventually. the other (non UI) option will not show warning. if your data is not totally huge (no numbers were given) both will run fast.

Comment: so any method will do the same way? i just tried `yes` but it's said `Time Out` . the data on production is absolutely huge , any other solutions?

Comment: you can increase your timeout as mentioned in the post. In the end it's mostly hardware times. setting timeout to 0 will mean unlimited timeout as mentioned.

Answer (score 8):

To fix it, go to the ***Tools Menu*** and select ***Options*** then under ***Designers*** select ***Table and Database Designers*** the first option allows you to disable the timeout, or make it greater than the default 30 seconds.

Ref: http://surf11.com/entry/197/saving-table-times-out-in-sql-server-200

Comment: is it safe? i just afraid that the data will corrupt ?

Comment: its safe as far as i understand. I have never had any issues with it but then again just like many things tech, it depends.

Answer (score 2):

There is two options for set time-out-execution time

**1. Tools > option > Designers > Transaction time-out after**

Set bigger value than 30 sec. (max 65536) this will fix that issue

but there is one more option

**2. Tools > option > Query Execution > Execution time-out**

Generaly this is not couse a problem because Default value is 0 (unlimited)
already but check this and fix it to 0 if you see different value there.

> It is completely safe and there is no possibilty to data corrupt.