# Adding a new column to a database table that has millions of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am adding a new column to a database table that has millions of rows. When i do this in SQL Server Management studio through table designer i am getting following warning.

> Saving Definition Changes to tables with large amounts of data could
>   take a considerable amount of time. While changes are being saved,
>   table data will not be accessible

Is there any other way i can avoid this long table locking? Will this be faster with SQL `Alter Table` statement.

Comment: Typically, yes, alter table is WAY faster than doing it through SSMS.

Comment: [dba-stackexchange: Adding columns to production tables](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4506/adding-columns-to-production-tables)

Comment: What happened when you tried both methods on a test database?

Comment: Actually After table one worked fine

Comment: In SSMS if you add the new column at the end of list of fields, you're basically just doing the ALTER TABLE statement. If you insert the new column somewhere else, SSMS has to do a LOT of work behind the scenes (create a new table with the new field ordering, copy all the data into the new table, drop the old table, then rename the new table to match the old one), which can take a lot of time and will usually time out in SSMS for large tables.

Comment: Also, if you are adding a new column that is non-NULL with a default value, it might be better to add it as a NULLable field first, then add the default value in chunks, then change the field to non-NULL and add the default constraint after it's been fully populated.

Comment: It may help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17609838/add-column-from-development-database-table-to-production-database-table